# Create a kotlin code to modify and generate a json file

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin

Before any further, I am trying this to work since a while but failing, spent a week now I got to know that here I can ask...if anybody is having some free time then only read below otherwise ignore BUT DO NOT FLAG PLEASE & tell me if this is not possible, ignore my ignorance :/

I need a kotlin code to create a json file in which-

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=",
    "copyright": "Protected by copyright, DO NOT USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES",
    "collections": "album1"
  },
]
```

The above is a container or prototype and what I need it to do is-

After I run the code it asks me '`enter all ids`', when I enter any amount of ids, for example I enter `844656565, 65648451` then it should copy the already entered snippet 2 times if i enter 2 ids, 3 times if i enter 3 ids and add the id after the `view&id=` in the first line end.

For instance, if i enter 7777, 8888 then it should create a json file with following code-

```
[
      {
        "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=",
        "copyright": "Protected by copyright, DO NOT USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES",
        "collections": "album1"
      },
{
        "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=7777",
        "copyright": "Protected by copyright, DO NOT USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES",
        "collections": "album1"
      },
 {
        "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=8888",
        "copyright": "Protected by copyright, DO NOT USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES",
        "collections": "album1"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to target JVM or Android, you may use Jackson databinding.

1. Add it as dependency.
   (Gradle: `dependencies { implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1") }`)
2. Create a class to describe this model.

```kotlin
data class Song(val url: String, val copyright: String, val collections: String)
```

3. Create functions to serialize/deserialize this class.

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

data class Song(val url: String, val copyright: String, val collections: String)

private val mapper by lazy { ObjectMapper() }

fun songsFromString(source: String) = mapper.readValue(source, Array<Song>::class.java)!!
fun songsToString(songs: Array<Song>) = mapper.writeValueAsString(songs)!!
```

It is not difficult to use this class and functions to create behavior you expect.